# vertically align TikZ snippet in text

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

When creating a TikZ snippet inside a figure caption, the snippet is never really aligned with the surrounding text. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{%
  (\protect\tikz \protect\node [circle,draw=black,minimum width=1em]{};)
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I suppose it all looks alright if the circle sits comfortably on the base line. How to get it there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give the node some (invisible) content and a name and use the `base` (or any other desired) anchor for `baseline`; you can also pass explicit lengths to `baseline` for finer control. The following example shows both options (I also set `inner sep=0pt` for the second example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{%
  (\protect\tikz[baseline=(circ.base)] \protect\node[circle,draw=black,minimum width=1em] (circ) {\protect\phantom{a}};)
    (\protect\tikz[baseline=-0.7ex] \protect\node[circle,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,text width=1em] (circ) {\protect\phantom{a}};)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The math mode command `\vcenter` centers its material around the math axis:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption{%
  (%
    $\vcenter{\hbox{%
      \protect\tikz \protect\node [circle,draw=black,minimum width=1em]{};%
    }}$%
  )%
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The additional `\hbox` prevents, that `\tikz` starts a new paragraph inside `\vcenter` with a full line width. Both `\vcenter` and `\hbox` are robust and do not need `\protect`.